# Dexie 2.0 beta - How does it work with async await?

Tags: javascript, dexie

How does the Dexie 2.0 beta work with async/await? I was reading through the source code but I am still confused how it is propagating zones without monkey patching any native functionality.  Can someone give me a high level overview of how this works?

I'm pretty interested in using Dexie, any info would be great!

Comment: What does this have to do with EcmaScript 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dexie monkey patches Promise temporarily when entering a transaction zone, and restores it when leaving zone. Note that Dexie has its own zone system but it cooperates well with angular zones.